# No se visualizan partes de mi web con webview en Android

Tags: java, android, wordpress-plugin

soy competamente novato y estoy intentando hacer una webview en Android Studio que muestre mi web. Todo funciona correctamente excepto una parte de la web que se muestra en blanco y no consigo saber el porque. El problema no está en la web porque utilizando app geyser (un generador de apps online) me genera una app en la que se ve toda la web sin problemas. La web es librevoz.com y lo que no me muestra es el contenido de los cursos que se generan en java mediante Learnpress (un plugin de Wordpress). El soporte para java está correctamente habilitado ya que se muestran muchas partes de la web que están hechas en java. Para comprobarlo puedes acceder al curso de iniciación al canto y entrar en la lección "confía en tu voz cree en ti" que está abierta para ver sin registrarse.
¡Muchas gracias por tu tiempo!

El código que estoy usando es este:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.librevoz.librevoz4">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />



</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.librevoz.librevoz4.MainActivity">


    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/activity_main_webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main.Activity.java

```
package com.librevoz.librevoz4;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

        // Enable Javascript
       WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
       webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
       mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

        mWebView.loadUrl("https://librevoz.com/");

        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

        // Stop local links and redirects from opening in browser instead of WebView
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(mWebView.canGoBack()) {
            mWebView.goBack();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
}
```

MyappwebCLient.java

```
package com.librevoz.librevoz4;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

/**
 * Created by vegas on 27/10/2017.
 */

public class MyAppWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if(Uri.parse(url).getHost().endsWith("librevoz.com")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Has probado a activar JavaScript? Webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

Comment: Hola, deberías agregar tu clase en android, para que te puedan ayudar.

Comment: Ya he incluido el código que estoy usando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EL PROBLEMA ES QUE ES INFRAME EL CONTENIDO DE LAS LECCIONES, INTENTA TENER EL CODIGO DE ÉSTA PARTE ASÍ

// INI AGREGADO
        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);

```
    // Activamos Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);


    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Url que carga la app (webview)
    mWebView.loadUrl("https://AQUI LA URL DE TU WEB.com");

    // Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces internos dentro de la la APP
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());

    // Forzamos el webview para que abra los enlaces externos en el navegador
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyAppWebViewClient());
    // FIN AGREGADO
}
```

Comment: Hola Gabriel. Bienvenido a [es.so]. Por favor, lee el [tour] para aprender el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Por favor, elimina la otra respuesta y en esta quita las mayusculas. Un saludo

Comment: gabriel, cual es la parte que supone corregir el problema???. Declaras WebViewClient pero también usas MyAppWebViewClient??,  =|